# How can I exit a multi-line command sequence in the Erlang shell?

Tags: erlang, erlang-shell

Sometimes in the Erlang shell, if I mistype a command and hit Enter, the shell goes to the next line in anticipation that the command will continue (so the line number on the left stays the same).

For example, I just now mistakenly (on purpose) typed `1> $"X".` instead of `1> $X.`. After hitting Enter, now the command line is stuck on `1>`. I have tried typing `.` followed by Enter and simply Enter in the hopes of terminating the command sequence, but it doesn't work. Although I have tried, it is very hard to look this up on google because the incredibly common keywords lead to other results.

Is there a way I can break that sequence without having to exit the shell entirely with Ctrl C? The trouble with restarting the shell is all the variables are lost.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can hit Ctrl-g, which gets you to the "User switch command" this erlang's **shell break mode**

The prompt will change from **>** to **--->**.

In this mode

- Type **i** to interrupt your erlang session
- then type **c** to reconnect to it

erlang shell will then state **exception exit: killed** and return to the state it was in immediately before you got stuck.

```
~ → erl
Erlang/OTP 19 [erts-8.2] [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false] [dtrace]

local recon loaded
local stdlib2 loaded
Eshell V8.2  (abort with ^G)
1> $"X".
1> l
1> .
1> .
1>
User switch command
 --> i
 --> c
** exception exit: killed
1> R=22.
22
2> $"X".
2>
User switch command
 --> i
 --> c
** exception exit: killed
2> b().
R = 22
ok
3>
```

Comment: I always used the ^G to start a new shell in the same node, I never tried the "i" command, THX

Answer (score 0):

I don't know an universal way, and I am interested to know one. On my side I try to figure out what the shell is expecting, in your example, the shell "thinks" that you are typing a string:

The first `$"` is interpreted as the character `'"'`, so the next `'"'` is interpreted as the beginning of a string and the shell is waiting for the end of the string before it starts to interpret the next dot as the end of expression.

Type `".` and you will get a new prompt.

**Edit**

When an error is detected by the shell directly, before evaluating the expression, the prompt number doesn't change because there is no result to store:

```
1> $"X".
1> ".
* 1: syntax error before: X
1> lists:seq(1,5). 
[1,2,3,4,5]
2>
```

If the error is detected during the evaluation of the input, the prompt number is incremented. from the shell point of view there is no difference between a successful evaluation and a faulty one, in both cases the evaluation returns a result:

```
2> lists:seq("1","5").
** exception error: no function clause matching lists:seq("1","5") (lists.erl, line 243)
3>
```

The results of each evaluation is stored by the shell, and it can be retrieved using v(N):

```
3> v(1).
[1,2,3,4,5]
4> v(2).
{'EXIT',{function_clause,[{lists,seq,
                                 ["1","5"],
                                 [{file,"lists.erl"},{line,243}]},
                          {erl_eval,do_apply,6,
                                    [{file,"erl_eval.erl"},{line,674}]},
                          {shell,exprs,7,[{file,"shell.erl"},{line,686}]},
                          {shell,eval_exprs,7,[{file,"shell.erl"},{line,641}]},
                          {shell,eval_loop,3,
                                 [{file,"shell.erl"},{line,626}]}]}}
5>
```

Comment: This is of course, but without always much success, what I have been trying to do. Usually, I give up after a couple of guesses to get back to the task at hand. Regarding what you wrote, it did not work immediately, but after a couple of repeats 
`5> $"A". 
5> ".
* 1: syntax error before: A
5> ".
5> ".
".\n"
6>`. Thanks for helping figure it out! By the way, any clues why I had to repeat it for the shell to finally get it?

Comment: the answer of @byaruhaf does the trick.. as I have now checked, the content of that answer is in chapter 10 of the "Programming Erlang" book 2nd edition..

Comment: I know that my answer is not the expected one, and I was interested by a generic solution :o)